# Excel Conditional Formatting: If TableColumn = value1 AND ValueFromSameRowButAnotherColumn = value2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

**Context:**

I'm working off of a template calendar that autofills a calendar if events and times are listed in a table in another tab.

From that table,
I've named the date column: **Dates**;
I've named the event column: **Event**

In the calendar, each date has 4 rows 1 column with the date in the first column (e.g. Row B).

**Problem:**

On the calendar, I want to **conditionally format** so that if the STAT holiday date si listed in the events table, then the 4 rows in the date is shaded grey.

I tried the following formulas but none of them work: =(IF then conditional format)

- =AND((Event="STAT"),(Dates=A$8))
- =(Event="STAT")*(Dates=B$4) --> Another question said the * worked the same as AND for conditional formatting

Basically, if the value in the 'Date Column' is the date in the calendar grid, AND if the Event, in the same row as the date referenced in the 'Date Column', is "STAT", then shade the cell grey.

Hope it was all clear, **thank you** in advance :)

Comment: Would you please include sample data and desirable results in your question? The business logic is a bit unclear from your description. Thanks and regards,

Comment: I don't think you can use table header names in conditional formatting formulas. You should be able to get the results you're looking for by referencing the cells, instead.

Comment: Hi Alex, the business results that I'd like from this is that when I put a new event with a new date into the events table, the calendar in the other tab would automatically update to include that event in the right date. The events marked with "STAT" would not only populate the calendar in the right date, it will also make it so that the other rows in the same date is shaded out.

Comment: Hi Kyle, I'd like for it the date grid inside the calendar to go through the event table to find all the events that occur on that day. The "STAT" event just happens to have a different name. Would you reference the whole table then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use conditional format to set the value of a cell so in the left cell on your calendar you'll have to put a formula somthing like this, assuming your events table is called EventsTable and is in Sheet1 (without sample data it's tricky):

`=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(*DateYouWantToLookUp*, *Sheet1!EventsTable*, 2)), "", VLOOKUP(*DateYouWantToLookUp*, *Sheet1!EventsTable*, 2))

And for the conditional formatting, assuming you calendar starts in A1, you'll need to use the following formula:

`=$D22="STAT"` and for the 'Applies to' area, you'll need to use `=$A$1:$D$XX` where XX=last row in you calendar.

Comment: Does this achieve the desired result? If not, let me know.